# jQuery selector: select all `li` elements after `li[id="control"]`

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list:

```
<ul>
   <li class="myclass">...</li>
   <li class="myclass">...</li>   
   <li class="myclass">...</li>
   <li id="control">...</li>
   <li class="myclass">...</li>
   <li class="myclass">...</li>
   <li class="myclass">...</li>
</ul>
```

How can I select all `li` elements after `li[id="control"]`?
In this example, I need to select last three `li`'s

Comment: Hold on, making a jsfiddle for it.

Comment: Nicks answer is the best, dude.

Comment: @Anonymous Loozah - well check out mine too, dude :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) which will get all *siblings* after a particular element selection, like this:

```
$("#control").nextAll();
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PV6UY/)

In this case the siblings are `<li>` elements, so it'll select all of them on the same level (not child `<li>`s beneath, if they exist).

Comment: Great! Did not even know about it. (Can't mark as answer (9 minutes rule))

Comment: thanks for motivating my race back to the api site where I learned about the "~" thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single selector, I *think* you can use `$('#control ~ li')`. The "~" connector (is "connector" the right word?  "operator" maybe?) is like "+", but it selects all following siblings and not just the first one.

Sometimes it's nice to be able to do things with a single selector string, because you may want to organize selectors and actions in a data structure.  However, it's quite often the case that doing explicit jQuery function calls in a chain (as in @Nick's answer with ".nextAll()") is faster than letting the selection engine parse and evaluate a fancy selector string.

Comment: Indeed you're right, the reason I use `.nextAll()` is it isn't as penalizing as going with the selector.  The `~ li` is more expensive since `~` isn't supported by `querySelectorAll()` it's much more work to evaluate that selector: http://jsperf.com/nextall-vs

Comment: Yes, that's why I really don't know much about all the fancy selector foo that jQuery supports - they're neat, but I almost never actually use that stuff.